# Show that the function $f(x)=\left(\sqrt{\frac{e}{2}}\cdot\frac{e}{\pi}\right)-\frac{1}{x}+\left(\frac{e}{2}-\frac{x}{e^{x}}\right)-x$ is negative

Tags: functions, inequality, constraints, constants

Hi I proposed a similar question some days ago and I cannot find the answer .Now the problem :

Let $0<x$ then we have :

$$f(x)=\left(\sqrt{\frac{e}{2}}\cdot\frac{e}{\pi}\right)-\frac{1}{x}+\left(\frac{e}{2}-\frac{x}{e^{x}}\right)-x<0$$

It's not hard to show the concavity of the function $f(x)$ for $x>0$ and then find the maxima at $x=1$

So remains to show that the particular value $f(1)$ is less than zero so negative .

Question :

Can we hope to show it by hand without calculated the extrema with a computer  ?

Ps:It seems very challenging .

Comment: Is *Pascaline* allowed ?

Comment: La plaisance de la pascaline ? if you see the annagramme dear .

Comment: You can use approximations such as $2.718281<e<2.718282$ and $3.141592<\pi<3.141593$. Isn't that ok with you?

Comment: I haven't looked at how precisely you have to push the calculations, but you can use bounds of e and pi. like for example the following inequalities: 2.7182818 <e <2.7182819, 3.1415926 <pi <3.1415927.

Comment: I cheated for the last division : I used my phone ! Cheers and thanks for one more nice problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use
$$e=\frac{193}{71} \quad \quad\sqrt e=\frac{61}{37} \quad\quad \sqrt 2=\frac{99}{70}\quad\quad \pi=\frac{333}{106}$$ and obtain
$$f(1)=-\frac{1505695}{33429263274}=-0.0000450412$$
Use
$$e=\frac{1071}{394} \quad \quad\sqrt e=\frac{582}{353} \quad\quad \sqrt 2=\frac{577}{408}\quad\quad \pi=\frac{355}{113}$$ and obtain
$$f(1)=-\frac{673314589}{61023141268740}=-0.0000110338$$